# How to write enum column in java pojo class?

Tags: java, hibernate

[image]In my database, I have a column of enum datatype. Below is the table structure.

```
CREATE TYPE STATUSENUM AS ENUM('Published','Draft','Expire');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T_COMMODITY_INSIGHT(
    ID integer NOT NULL,
    COMMODITY_ID integer NOT NULL,
    CREATED_DATE date NOT NULL,
    MODIFIED_DATE date NOT NULL,
    STATUS STATUSENUM DEFAULT 'Draft',
    CONSTRAINT "T_COMMODITY_INSIGHT_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

In my POJO class, How do I write enum column with getter & setter method along with the parametrized constructor which accepts the value entered by the user & How do I make sure that entered value of enum column has to be the one defined in the database?

I am using Hibernate.

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: Show us the POJO class. Are you using JPA?

Comment: @Lorelorelore - Yes, Hibernate

Comment: good question anyway voted up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPA you can use this in your java class file:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status")
private StatusEnum status = StatusEnum.DRAFT;

public StatusEnum getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(StatusEnum status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

StatusEnum:

```
public enum StatusEnum {
    DRAFT, SENT
}
```

Comment: - Do we need to create a separate class or Interface of StatusEnum type? because I am bit confused about how to write in pojo class.

Comment: Hey Spara - I did the same but I am getting an error ->


org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "status" is of type statusenum but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: @AyushGoyal you should not create StatusEnum table, just delete that table and create a column names `stats` that is type of `varchar(255)`

Comment: Hey Spara - It worked. Very much thanks to you :) But now, how do I set the default value for the field status. let's say Draft.

Comment: @AyushGoyal you can have default value for varchar columns like this : `state VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Draft'`

Comment: Hey Spara - I did the same but it is inserting NULL value in the 'status' column when I skip status field in json.

STATUS text DEFAULT 'Draft',

my json:

{
 "id" : 5,
 "insight" : "test",
 "createdBy" : "abc",
 "createdDate" : "2018-07-11",
 "modifiedDate" : "2018-07-11",
 "commodityTest" : {
  "commodityId" : 1,
  "name" : "test",
  "createdDate" : "2018-07-10",
  "modifiedDate" : "2018-07-10"
 }
}

Here, I am skipping the status field.

Comment: @AyushGoyal maybe you are passing null value instead of nothing in your query

Comment: Yes, By default it is taking NULL value when I skip the status field in the input json but it should take the default value when I don't pass anything & according to the enum concept, it should take only one of those value that we have defined in the enum like:

public enum StatusEnum {
    DRAFT, SENT
}

Comment: @AyushGoyal yes I updated answer for default value. you can assign default value to column like this : `private StatusEnum status = StatusEnum.DRAFT;`

Comment: Hey Spara - Thank you very much for your help throughout :)